# Telnet Terminal F3 Key Transmit

Tags: linux, terminal, telnet, keyboard

I am creating a new install image for deployment, upgrading from a previous deployment of Fedora Core 4 to Linux Mint 15. I have the telnet session to the server working and all keys are operating as expected, with one exception and that is the F3 key.

Wireshark & Ethereal have enabled me to ascertain what data is being transmitted between the client and server. We use Anzio (Telnet client) under windows and xterm under linux Fedora Core.

Under xorg.conf for both keyboard models the XkbModel is set to pc105, and XkbLayout is set to "us". I am wondering if this is an issue in relation to the terminal type.

Below is the relative data transmitted to the server on Keypress of the required function keys. Green indicates the key is working as expected.

http://i39.tinypic.com/2rwrfar.jpg

If anyone can provide advice as to how I can modify or set \033OR or change the mint terminal to send the same keycodes as that of either Anzio or Fedora, I would be most appreciative.

Should I remain with Fedora and KDE rather than changing to Gnome, is this where the issue lies?

Thanks

Comment: You are using the 'install image' as a terminal emulator to remote system, correct?

Comment: Yes I am at this point trying to get the terminal emulator to send the correct commands via telnet to our POS system, once this is working I am then going to use Mondo Rescue to create an image that I can quickly install on around 100 devices. In short, when I press the F3 key the server should respond with data, it is however not responding with anything.